# How to add to the startup script?

Tags: crash

My Elementary OS freezes and crashes on coping large files. I try [apply a fix](https://blog.realhe.ro/linux/when-copying-a-large-file-on-linux-transfer-hangs-at-the-end-and-you-want-to-fking-kill-someone/) I did find on Ubuntu forums: to change content of two files.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo $((48*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes'
sudo sh -c 'echo $((16*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes'
```

Sadly after every single reboot, the contents of these two files resets. Which one is the right way to add the above command to the startup?

- create a startup script or
- add the below lines to an existing startup script? (which one is that?)

Answer (score 1):

Add them to the bottom of the .profile file in your home directory. In the terminal:

```
io.elementary.code ~/.profile
```

Append the scripts, save, then reboot and you should be in business.

Comment: I am a beginner. Could You please be more specific what to do? How to append the scripts? You mean the ~/.profile and which one is the other one? Wont be any problem that I need root privileges for these:  
`sudo sh -c 'echo $((48*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes'  
sudo sh -c 'echo $((16*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes' `

Comment: I failed to notice that you are running your scripts as sudo. I'll respond back later when I have a few minutes with a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `gnome-session-properties` you can set any command to run after a system startup. Just run it on Terminal and then press "Add", and after that you need to write the script in the given textbox.